# Function not waiting for intended period of time - Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I have a function that returns me the element based on xpath.

```
DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SEC = 10
def wait_for_element_by_xpath(self, xpath,
                                  wait_time=DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SEC):
        print ("wait_time")
        print (wait_time)
        result = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, wait_time)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        return self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
```

I kept the default timeout time to 10 seconds intentionally.

```
        timeValue = "//span[contains(text(),'online Time')]"
        self.wait_for_element_by_xpath(timeValue, 70)
```

I have passed 70 seconds to this particular call to wait for element to appear on screen. But when I run my test, it only waits for 10 seconds and throw NoSuchElementException.

I printed wait_time in my function intentionally to check what time is it picking, default time or my given time (70 sec).

wait_time prints 70.

So why is it throwing exception after 10 seconds and not waiting for intended 70 sec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `result = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)` line from function definition. Try below code:

```
DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SEC = 10
def wait_for_element_by_xpath(self, xpath,
                                  wait_time=DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SEC):
        print ("wait_time is %s" % wait_time)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, wait_time)
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        return element
```